# How to overlay divs with pure css?

Tags: css

To create this effect:

[image]

It is possible or would I need to design it with software?

Comment: What have you tried? Please show, at the very lest an attempt to answer your own question.

Comment: are this a single element or are those two different elements? Which browser do you need to support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use gradient as background

```
div {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg,  #1e5799 50%, #207cca 50%, #7db9e8 100%); 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(50%,#1e5799),   color-stop(50%,#207cca), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8));    
    ...
}
```

An example :  http://jsfiddle.net/w9fYj/

Comment: Thanks, I think that is exactly what I expected! Where could be ajusted the merge position? In your eg is right at middle

Comment: @goodguy_cakephp you could change the merge position if you increase or decrease the colors percentage 'background: linear-gradient(135deg, #1e5799 66%,#207cca 50%,#7db9e8 100%);' and example : http://jsfiddle.net/w9fYj/2/

Comment: Thumbs up :) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with triangles (which basically works on border adjustments) [How do CSS triangles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073484/how-does-this-css-triangle-shape-work)

And other shapes for [more](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/qG65q/42/)

Here is extensive example with transforms of many divisions which may interest you.

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/9JFDq/1/)**</kbd>

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="shape3">
        <div class="shape3-content">Hi there!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="shape1">
        <div class="shape1-content">Hi there!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="shape2">
        <div class="shape2-content">Hi there!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid #ff8888;
    height: 480px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -240px 0 0 -320px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 640px;
}
.shape1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(15deg);
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 50%;
    left: -25%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 70%;
    width: 150%;
}
.shape1-content {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg);
    padding-left: 230px;
}
.shape2 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(15deg);
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #88ff88;
    bottom: 244px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    width: 100%;
}
.shape2-content {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-15deg);
    bottom: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}
.shape3 {
    background:red;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(30deg);
    border: 1px solid #8888ff;
    bottom: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 20%;
    width: 100%;
}
.shape3-content {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    bottom: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is using pure CSS:

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#test {
    widh:300px;
    height:150px;
    background:#C3C3C3;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#test:after {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    right:-100px;
    top:10px;
    transform:rotate(-30deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-30deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-30deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-30deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-30deg);
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
    background:#880015;
}
```

And here is a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Karim_AG/a2Xzu/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

If you consider to support old browsers without using CSS3 then:

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="middle"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
}
.left {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.right {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    background-color: #610A0A;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
.middle {
    float:left;
    display: inline;
    line-height: 0%;
    width: 0px;
    border-top: 100px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 100px solid #610A0A;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5wyb8/)**